# Crystal reports expoert to PDf file size is too large

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, export-to-pdf

here is my problem.  I have an RPT file which  I am exporting to PDF.  when I give  my entire table from my dataset and export the rpt to PDF the file created is around 25 MB. and all the statements are  joined.  now when I give individual records from the dataset to the rpt file and create new file for each statement they are around 80 kb to 250 kb each totaling in about 650 MB.  is there a way I can reduce the size of the  files for my second option to say 150 MB for all of the records ?

any workaround ?
 if need be I can post my solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf;



namespace PrintSinglaStatementAtTime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            OracleConnection connection;
            OracleDataAdapter OracleAdapter;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            int one=1;
            int two = 1;
            int three = 1;
            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document;
            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page;
            XGraphics gfx;
            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 8);


            connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

            connection.Open();
            OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatementTable"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "domestic");
            OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MetaDataTable"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "MetaDataDetail");
            connection.Close();

            ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
            reportDoc.Load(@"c:\users\desktop\statement2.rpt");
            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

            CrExportOptions = reportDoc.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;

            }

            string XmlFilename = "";
            DataTable stmt = ds.Tables["MetaDataDetail"];
            stmt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { stmt.Columns["statementnumber"] };
            stmt.Columns["custname"].ColumnName = "CustomerName";
            stmt.Columns["custid"].ColumnName = "CustomerNumber";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_addr1"].ColumnName = "CustomerStreet1";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_addr2"].ColumnName = "CustomerStreet2";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_addr3"].ColumnName = "CustomerStreet3";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_city"].ColumnName = "CustomerCity";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_state"].ColumnName = "CustomerState";
            stmt.Columns["soldto_zip"].ColumnName = "CustomerZip";
            stmt.Columns["PackagePagecount"].ColumnName = "PackagePageCount";
            stmt.Columns["sequence"].ColumnName = "SequenceNumber";


            var stmtnumber = "";
            int pgcount1oz = 1;
                 int pgcount2oz = 1;
                 int pgcount3oz = 1;
                 PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

                 ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < stmt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stmtnumber = stmt.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                 var  exp = GetFilteredTable(ds.Tables["domestic"], stmtnumber);


                 reportDoc.SetDataSource(exp);
                 CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = @"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf";

                 reportDoc.Export();

               // var NumberofPages = GetNoOfPagesPDF(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");         
                 document = PdfReader.Open(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

                 int counter = document.PageCount;

                 if (counter < 4)
                 {

                     for (int idx = 0; idx < counter; idx++)
                     {
                         page = document.Pages[idx];
                          gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);


                         if (idx == 0)
                         {

                             gfx.DrawString(one.ToString("00000") + "  " + pgcount1oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                                 new XRect(230, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                                 XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                             pgcount1oz++;

                         }
                         else if (idx>0
                             ) {
                             gfx.DrawString(pgcount1oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                                     new XRect(236, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                                     XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                             pgcount1oz++;
                         }
                     }
                     string filename = @"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf";
                     document.Save(filename);



                     DataRow tbe = stmt.Rows.Find(stmtnumber);
                     tbe["packagepagecount"] = counter;
                     tbe["SequenceNumber"] = one;
                     one++;
                 }
                 else if (counter > 4 || counter < 9)
                 {
                     for (int idx = 0; idx < counter; idx++)
                     {
                  page = document.Pages[idx];
                          gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                         if (idx == 0)
                         {
                             gfx.DrawString(two.ToString("00000") + "  " +  pgcount2oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                                 new XRect(230, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                                 XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                             pgcount2oz++;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             gfx.DrawString(                        "  " + pgcount2oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                                     new XRect(236, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                                     XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                             pgcount2oz++;
                         }
                     }
                     string filename = @"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf";
                     document.Save(filename);



                     DataRow tbe = stmt.Rows.Find(stmtnumber);
                     tbe["packagepagecount"] = counter;
                     tbe["SequenceNumber"] = two;
                     two++;

                 }
                 else if ( counter > 9)
                 {
                     for (int idx = 0; idx < counter; idx++)
                     {
                          page = document.Pages[idx];
                          gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);


                         if (idx==0)
                         { gfx.DrawString(three.ToString("00000")+"  "+pgcount3oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                             new XRect(230, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                             XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                         pgcount3oz++;
                     }

                     else {

                          gfx.DrawString(                          "  "+pgcount3oz.ToString("00000"), font, XBrushes.Black,

                             new XRect(236, 130, page.Width, page.Height),
                             XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                          pgcount3oz++;
                     }
                     }
                     string filename = @"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf";
                     document.Save(filename);



                     DataRow tbe = stmt.Rows.Find(stmtnumber);
                     tbe["packagepagecount"] = counter;
                     tbe["SequenceNumber"] = three;
                     three++;

                 }

                // RecompressExistingImages(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", @"d:\pdf\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");
                 #region joining pdf .. needs work 
                // byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");
                // File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\pdf\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf",bytes);

                 //FileStream ReadPdf = new FileStream(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", FileMode.Open);
                 //long FileSize;
                 //FileSize = ReadPdf.Length;
                 //byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
                 //ReadPdf.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)ReadPdf.Length);
                 //ReadPdf.Close();
                 //FileStream CreatePdf = new FileStream(@"d:\pdf\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf",
                 //FileMode.Create);
                 //CreatePdf.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                 //CreatePdf.Close();


                 #endregion 

                 var filtered = stmt.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<string>("statementnumber") == stmtnumber);
                     DataView z = filtered.AsDataView();
                DataTable ccc = z.ToTable();
                 XmlFilename = @"d:\XML\" + stmtnumber + ".xml";
                System.IO.FileStream streamWrite = new System.IO.FileStream (XmlFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
             ccc.WriteXml(streamWrite);
             streamWrite.Close();
             ccc.Clear();
             XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@"d:\XML\" + stmtnumber + ".xml");
             var snumber = xEle.Elements("MetaDataDetail").Elements("STATEMENTNUMBER").ToList();
             foreach (XElement PLE in snumber)
                 PLE.Remove();
             xEle.Save(@"d:\XML\" + stmtnumber + ".xml");

            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time :{0}", sw.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("one Oz :{0}   \n two oz {1} \n Three Oz {2}", pgcount1oz, pgcount2oz, pgcount3oz);


            Console.Read();
        }
        public static DataTable GetFilteredTable(DataTable dt, object statementNumber)
        {
            var detailRows = dt.Select(String.Format("statementnumber = {0}", statementNumber));
            var filteredDt = dt.Clone();
            foreach (var detailRow in detailRows)
            {
                filteredDt.Rows.Add(detailRow.ItemArray);
            }
            return filteredDt;
        }
        public static int GetNoOfPagesPDF(string FileName)
        {
            int result = 0;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);

            string pdfText = r.ReadToEnd();

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(pdfText);

            result = matches.Count;

            return result;
        }
        public static int sort(string stmtnumber,int PageCount )
        {

            if (PageCount <= 4)
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", @"d:\pdf\1oZ\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");
            }
            else if (PageCount > 4 || PageCount <= 9)
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", @"d:\pdf\2oZ\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");
            }
            else if (PageCount >= 9)
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(@"d:\pdf1\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf", @"d:\pdf\3oZ\" + stmtnumber + ".pdf");
            }

            return 0;

        }
        static void RecompressExistingImages(string fileName, string outputName)
        {
            using (BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf.PdfDocument(fileName))
            {
                foreach (PdfImage image in doc.Images)
                    image.RecompressWithJpeg();

                doc.Save(outputName);
            }
        }
        //private static void MergeMultiplePDFIntoSinglePDF(string outputFilePath, string[] pdfFiles)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Merging started.....");
        //    PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
        //    foreach (string pdfFile in pdfFiles)
        //    {
        //        PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        //        outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;
        //        foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
        //        {
        //            outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
        //        }
        //    }
        //    outputPDFDocument.Save(outputFilePath);
        //    Console.WriteLine("Merging Completed");
        //}

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are there images in your report? How many records are we talking about?

Comment: just one image  and it is not too big. we have a current program that produces the same result but the pdf file size is much less. the current data is about  10k statements,  and with old program the pdf created is about 110 MB.  when I used the same data and create a report it is 750 MB.

Comment: 10k _statements_ (by that I assume you mean sub/queries) or _records?_ Have you tried using the Crystal Reports Viewer (or CR itself) to export to PDF?

Comment: 10 K records.  I have tried using export all data in single pdf it comes to be around 20 megs. but when I split the PDF it goes to 750 MB.

Comment: Even 25MB seems extremely high to me. Without access to the report, the best I can tell you is to remove as much non-vital content as possible (images, unused fields, whitespace, etc).

Comment: The thing is a program that is in production already with same rpt file has output of 120 MB for all statements(lets say for this moth there are 9,000 statements), I have the same data in my program but the output is 795 MB.

Answer (score 1):

There are command line tools that can recompress PDF files to make them smaller:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-to-reduce-pdf-filesize

Answer (score 1):

if someone comes looking for same kind of problem here  is the solution.

PDF file exported for every records has header information containing the information such as fonts , size etc.

Solution was fairly simple. I created block of data and ran it though to export to PDF.  meaning single document with all the records.  there was no other work around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
                    DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                    PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
                    CrExportOptions = doc.ExportOptions;
                    {
                        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                    }
                    doc.Export();
```

Try this code for convert to pdf